# Need help regarding adjoints

Tags: functional-analysis

I encountered a definiton of the adjoint of an operator which uses Inner Product to define it.
Later I came across a problem which asks us to find the adjont of a linear map

$T(x_1,x_2, \dots) =(0, x_1,x_2, \dots)$
But I know that $ \ell^p$ is not an innerproduct space when $p\neq 2$
Now what am I supposed to find its adjoint?
Can someone help me out?

Comment: You can also define an adjoint of $T: E \to F$ in terms of dual maps $T^*: F^* \to E^*$ from their dual spaces, in this case the dual of $\ell^p$ is $\ell^q$ for $1/p + 1/q = 1$.

Comment: Is $T$ defined on $\ell^1$ or $\ell^2$ here?